# insert variables INSERT command Oracle using Python

Tags: python, oracle

I have a table in Oracle DB that I am trying to insert multiple rows into using a python script.

The table accepts the following fields with the datatypes specified
Columns - DataTypes

```
TAG - NUMBER(38,0)
TAG_ID - NUMBER(38,0)
TAG_STATUS - NUMBER(38,0)
GROUP_ID - NUMBER(38,0)
LIC_PLATE - VARCHAR(20 BYTE)
LIC_PLATE_ID - CHAR(2 BYTE)
```

The sql query I am using,

```
q = ("INSERT INTO TABLE (TAG, TAG_ID, TAG_STATUS_ID, GROUP_ID, LIC_PLATE, LIC_PLATE_ID) VALUES (var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)")
```

where var1 to var6, I am reading from a csv file. For e.g. a row in csv file gives me

```
var1 = '11011'
var2 = 25
var3 = 1
var4 = 66
var5 = 'BSB261'
var6 = 'IN'
```

when I try to execute using the above information it obviously fails

```
cursor.execute(q)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

I have looked into executemany() and other examples but I think I cant get the right format expected by the table

Note howvever that the following query would works just fine where I have the values hardcoded

```
q = ("INSERT INTO TABLE (TAG, TAG_ID, TAG_STATUS_ID, GROUP_ID, LIC_PLATE, LIC_PLATE_ID) VALUES (11011, 25, 1, 66, 'BSB261', 'IN')")
```

Any help is appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: your query string is wrong, just print it aout and you will see that you dont have real values in that string. to pass the values you have to do like
`q= "INSERT INTO TABLE (a, b) VALUES ('%s', '%d')" ('abc', 10)`

Comment: thanks but I think you missed the question as I am looking to put variables and not hard coded values into the query. Your suggestion is using the hard coded values and if I replace that with variables. It doesn't work again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to do this so writing my own answer(there might be better ways to do this so feel free to add comments for improvements)

`q = "INSERT INTO TABLE (TAG, TAG_ID, TAG_STATUS_ID, GROUP_ID, LIC_PLATE, LIC_PLATE_ID) VALUES(:TAG, :TAG_ID, :TAG_STATUS_ID, :GROUP_ID, :LIC_PLATE, :LIC_PLATE_ID)"`

then do:

`curs.execute(q, TAG=var1, TAG_ID=var2, TAG_STATUS_ID=var3, GROUP_ID=var4, LIC_PLATE=var5, LIC_PLATE_ID=var6)`